# C# Converting an array to a list

Tags: c#, arrays, list, file-io, command-line

I am working on an assignment that deals with file input and output. The instructions are as follows:

Write a program to update an inventory file. Each line of the inventory file will have a product number, a product name and a quantity separated by vertical bars. The transaction file will contain a product number and a change amount, which may be positive for an increase or negative for a decrease. Use the transaction file to update the inventory file, writing a new inventory file with the update quantities. I have provided 2 Input files to test your program with as well as a sample output file so you see what it should look like when you are done.

Hints:

1. This program requires 3 files
   Initial Inventory File
   File showing updates to be made
   New Inventory File with changes completed
2. Use Lists to capture the data so you don’t have to worry about the number of items in the files

Each line of the Inventory file looks something like this:

123 | television | 17

I have also been given the basic structure and outline of the program:

```
class Program
{
    public class InventoryNode
    {
     // Create variables to hold the 3 elements of each item that you will read from the file
     // Make them all public 

        public InventoryNode()
        {
         // Create a constructor that sets all 3 of the items to default values
        }

        public InventoryNode(int ID, string InvName, int Number)
        {
         // Create a constructor that sets all 3 of the items to values that are passed in          
 }

        public override string ToString()   // This one is a freebie
        {
            return IDNumber + " | " + Name + " | " + Quantity;
        }
    }

    static void Main(String[] args)
    {
 // Create variables to hold the 3 elements of each item that you will read from the file
 // Create variables for all 3 files (2 for READ, 1 for WRITE)

        List<InventoryNode> Inventory = new List<InventoryNode>();
        InventoryNode Item = null;

 // Create any other variables that you need to complete the work

        // Check for proper number of arguments
            // If there are not enough arguments, give an error message and return from the program
     // Otherwise
            // Open Output File
            // Open Inventory File (monitor for exceptions)
            // Open Update File (monitor for exceptions)
            // Read contents of Inventory into the Inventory List
            // Read each item from the Update File and process the data
            // Write output file

        //Close all files

        return;
    }
}
```

There is a lot of steps to this problem but right now I am only really concerned with how to read the inventory file into a list. I have read files into arrays before, so I thought I could do that and then convert the array to a list. But I am not entirely sure how to do that. Below is what I have created to add to the main method of the structure above.

```
        int ID;
        string InvName;
        int Number;

        string line; 

        List<InventoryNode> Inventory = new List<InventoryNode>();
        InventoryNode Item = null;

        StreamReader f1 = new StreamReader(args[0]);
        StreamReader f2 = new StreamReader(args[1]);
        StreamWriter p = new StreamWriter(args[2]);


        // Read each item from the Update File and process the data
        while ((line = f1.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            string[] currentLine = line.Split('|');
            {

                ID = Convert.ToInt16(currentLine[0]);
                InvName = currentLine[1];
                Number = Convert.ToInt16(currentLine[2]);

            }

        }
```

I am a bit hung up on the `Inventory Node Item = null;` line. I am not really sure what this is supposed to be doing. I really just want to read the file to an array so I can parse it and then pass that data to a list. Is there a way to do that that is something similar to the block I have written? Maybe there is a simpler way. I am open to that, but I figured I'd show my train of thought.

Comment: They want you to use `InventoryNode`'s constructor so it'll be: `Inventory.add(new InventoryNode(Convert.ToInt16(currentLine[0]), currentLine[1], Convert.ToInt16(currentLine[2]))`

Comment: Also not sure what all those `StreamReaders` are, you can use a foreach loop `foreach (var line in File.ReadLines(path))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# pass file text to list when file is entered via command line argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53330435/c-sharp-pass-file-text-to-list-when-file-is-entered-via-command-line-argument)  Please do not repost the same question over and over

Answer (score 0):

There is not need to add everything to an array and then convert it to the list.  `InventoryNode Item = null` is there to represent a line from the file.

You're pretty close. You just need to instantiate the `InventoryNode` and feed it the results of the `split()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. You already have fetched ID, InvName and Number, so you just have to instantiate the InventoryNode:

```
Item = new InventoryNode(...);
```

And then add `Item` to your list.

Note that `Inventory Node Item = null;` is not doing much; it just declares a variable that you can use later. This wasn't strictly necessary as the variable could have been declared inside the loop instead.